# Transform data from response to array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, fetch

It's schema from api:

Array[0,1,2,3,4,5] with object inside it:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3mSw.png)

---

I'm fetching data like this:

```
    fetch('http://localhost:50647/fund/GetFunds?MaxPageSize=100&Offset=5&Limit=5')
    
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();

    }).then(data => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
      })
      console.log(data);

    }).catch(err => {
    });
```

How can i transform and parse this data to **PRODUCTS** array?

Comment: try this: `let result = data.items.map(el => ({ title: el.title, description: el.description })); console.log('result', result);`

Comment: Ok, its works, when i using console.log, the data is filtered.

Now how can I assign an array of 'el' to the constant PRODUCTS, on which I will perform subsequent operations in the logic of frontends

Comment: make the result variable global, and change the value in `componentDidMount` method. but that will not be a good idea

Comment: @PiotrŻak Create a DataSource class, and do the network call there, and store it inside the class.. and cache it.. **Global** variable is not a good idea. Also ask a new questions for this, don't edit the question with new ideas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.map` on the `data.items` collection.

```
const products = data.map(obj => ({title: obj.title, description: obj.description}))
this.setState({isLoaded: true, products})
```

Comment: How make this variable global? Use let?

Comment: @PiotrŻak That will be bad idea, design. Why do you want to make a global variable?